# Start electron app with admin privileges as default

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I created an electron app which can only be started as admin, because it needs it for various command executions. Now it prompts that it must be started as admin.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45448049/run-electron-app-as-admin-windows) question was very helpful.

Now I want to start it with admin privileges right away so windows asks for the acception. It shouldn't be able to start the app without admin privileges.

I tried adding `--win32metadata.requested-execution-level=requireAdministrator`, but then it writes an error on startup (always):

> The application has failed to start because the side by side configuration is incorrect.

**How can I achive this with the electron packager?**

Comment: do you need this for a packaged app or non-packaged app?

Comment: @Ajey Packaged, it says "_with electron packager_"

Answer (score 3):

Your electron-packager code looks fine, and the switch works for me.

This can happen if you are missing Visual C++ Runtimes, or if they're corrupted. Try installing them from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) and try again.

If that doesn't help, then you should dig into the [Event Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer), which should come installed on your machine, and see what the specific error is. [This page](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/solved_the_application_has_failed_to_start_because_its_side_by_side_configuration_is_incorrect_error.html) has some additional tips on troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: I'm getting this error in event viewer, which is not covered on the linked site. `Activation context generation failed for "-REDACTED-PATH-".Error in manifest or policy file "-REDACTED-PATH-" on line 0. Invalid Xml syntax.`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Good to know. I think this is consistent with the hypothesis that something is corrupted or not installed correctly.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Do you see the error after trying my suggestion, or just before?

Comment: This is after. On the site you linked, in step 2, it has a 3rd party installer which I used. I got the same error before and after installing that.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Have you tried with the non-third party installer? Also, can you look at that file (Redacted Path), and see what it looks like? Is that file a Windows thing, or something else? Can you feasibly reinstall/repair the install of the application that the broken file relates to?

Comment: That path leads to the .exe file that electron-packager creates that runs the application, i've tried rebuilding the application multiple times. When I run this file, I get the error message which is in the original question in a pop up. This works perfectly fine without the `--win32metadata.requested-execution-level=requireAdministrator` flag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190254/discussion-between-grumpycrouton-and-pushkin).